# .NET, ASIO, DSP - how to start?

Tags: .net, audio, multimedia

1. How to send raw audio data to soundcard/get raw data from input?
2. How to control sound card hardware dsp (equalizer in Audigy for example) from .NET?
3. How to start with audio signal processing in .NET? Are there any free libraries/assemblies?

Im not bad C# programmer, but i never had to deal with multimedia, sound etc.

Any tips will be appreciate. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for start you should look into nAudio library:
http://naudio.codeplex.com/

Here are some tutorials how to use it:
http://www.giawa.com/tutorials/

Comment: `giawa.com/tutorials` seem to be gone but can be found at http://www.youtube.com/user/GiawaVideos

Comment: Although the wordpress site is down, all of the source code can still be snagged from that location.  Just check out the src directory.  As WojtekT mentioned, the youtube channel is still active.